# transaction and rollback in ef6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I currently have a (2) step process in EF6 and MVC5, to update 2 different tables. Updating the second table is dependent on getting a key value after the first table updates. How do I accomplish this wrapped in a transaction? This is what I currently am doing.

```
 db.tblFollowUpSurveys.Add(Survey);
            try
                {
                db.SaveChanges();
                // using the ID parameter search the tblsurvey table and return the surveyid

                tblFollowUpSurvey baseFUPSurvey = new tblFollowUpSurvey();
                tblFollowUp baseFUPS = new tblFollowUp();
                tblSystemConstant baseSC = new tblSystemConstant();

                baseSC = (from s in db.tblSystemConstants
                          select s).First();

                baseFUPSurvey = (from a in db.tblFollowUpSurveys
                                 where a.ID == ID
                                 select a).First();

                baseFUPS = (from b in db.tblFollowUps
                                  where b.ID == ID && b.FollowUpYear == baseSC.FollowUpYear
                                  select b).First();

                if (baseFUPS != null)
                    {
                    baseFUPS.SurveyID = baseFUPSurvey.SurveyId;
                    baseFUPS.SurveyPSN = PSN;
                    baseFUPS.SurveyType = "SL";
                    baseFUPS.SurveyStatus = "SELF";
                    baseFUPS.ModifiedBy = "Self";
                    baseFUPS.ContactMethod = "S";
                    baseFUPS.SurveyDate = DateTime.Now;
                    baseFUPS.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                    try
                        {
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return ("Record Saved");
                        }
                    catch
                        {
                        return ("Record not Saved");
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    return ("No FollowUp record found");
                    }
                }
            catch
                {
                return ("Record not Saved");
                }
```

So this is how I resolved this

```
public string postSurveyResults(vmFollowUpSurvey model, int PSN, string ID)
{
using (MVCEntities context = new MVCEntities() )
    {
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
        try
            {
            tblSurvey Survey = new tblSurvey();
                {
                code assignment
                };
            context.tblSurveys.Add(Survey);
            context.SaveChanges();

            tblUp baseFUPS = new tblUp();
            tblConstant baseSC = new tblConstant();
            baseSC = (from s in context.tblConstants
                      select s).First();

            baseFUPS = (from b in context.tblUps
                              where b.ID == ID && b.Year == baseSC.Year
                              select b).First();

                baseFUPS.ID = Survey.Id;
                code assignments


            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
            return "Record Saved";

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            transaction.Rollback();
            return ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to do that, you can use the reference of one not yet created instance and set it to the containing instance of another to be created instance. The db will create them both and set the appropriate PK and corresponding FK. Also do not swallow your exceptions, you are losing all the detail the way you have it now and you will never know why something failed (very bad practice!).

Comment: Finally please format your code so it is legible, all the unnecessary and arbitrary indentation makes it difficult to follow. If you find that difficult to do in the online editor then format your code in NotePad or some other editor and then copy/paste it back into your question.

Comment: So again the question is: How do you reference the value that the first Add creates into the second Add. The value in the second table is not set up as a FK.